# Create a method to aggregate data instead of update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site

  has_one :metric, dependent: :destroy
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And I would like to create an endpoint that, when called, aggregates the data sent, instead of just updating it. So, in my routes I changed the usual `put "metrics", to: "metrics#update` to `patch "metrics", to: "metrics#update`, and my controller looks like this:

```
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:update]

  def update
    # TODO
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

The first thing to notice is that instead of a usual `METHOD /{id}`, all routes should be called passing a `post_id` instead. Although this might sound weird, it makes sense for my use case – wordpress blogs all over the world (hopefully haha) will send metrics to this endpoint, and the only thing they know to do it is their unique id (`site_id`) + the wordpress blog post id (the one stored in wordpress database – I'm calling it `post_id` in my database).

For the sake of example, let's say that my model has only this columns:

```
sentiment
word_count
paragraph_length
```

Now, I would like your help with the following: how can I valid if those properties are present in the request body?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Presath should be fine. Its also good to have model-level validation too. E.g:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :sentiment, message: "can't be blank"
  validates_presence_of :word_count, message: "can't be blank"
  validates_presence_of :paragraph_length, message: "can't be blank"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following private method and call it before update to check if params are present

```
def is_params_present?
  ["sentiment","word_count","paragraph_length"].all? {|k| params.has?(k) && params[k].present?}
end
```